# How can only certain users see the page?

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. I have several users and these users can have different `rank`s. I have a page but I want to just one rank (`lead`) can see these page. How can I do that?

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    ranks = (
        ('analyst', 'Analyst'),
        ('seniorAnalyst', 'Senior Analyst'),
        ('lead', 'Lead'),
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('seniorManager', 'Senior Manager'),
        ('director', 'Director'),
        ('regionalDirector', 'Regional Director'),
        ('cfo', 'Chief Financial Officer'),
    )
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def lead_page(request):

    return render(request, 'lead.html')
```

Comment: Are these ranks essentially the basis of a permission/group system?

Comment: No It is just a model choicefield. And I will use it only one page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django's [**user_passes_test**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator for this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def is_lead(user):
    return user.rank == 'lead'


@user_passes_test(is_lead)
@login_required
def lead_page(request):

    return render(request, 'lead.html')
```

Comment: it is very useful, efficient and works great!

Comment: I have an another question. If you can answer that too, I would be very happy. I want to create a button in the users profile that opens this page. But again only "lead"s can see this button. There is a way to solve that?

Comment: You can use session variable and context processors to pass the user's role to the template and show/hide the button accordingly.